# a list of dataframes: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the example code/data I am working with. The issue I am having is that when the dataframe is empty with this condition `df[df['item_name'] == 'hp'` I would be getting an `index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with 0 message`. What would be the best way to correct this code to ignore the indexerror message?

```
import pandas as pd
#Creating a set of dataframes
data = {'product_name': ['laptop', 'printer', 'tablet', 'desk', 'chair'],'item_name': ['hp', 'logitech', 'samsung', 'lg', 'lenovo'],
        'price': [1200, 150, 300, 450, 200]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2 = {'product_name': ['laptop', 'printer', 'tablet', 'desk', 'chair'],'item_name': ['hp', 'mac', 'fujitsu', 'lg', 'asus'],
        'price': [2200, 200, 300, 450, 200]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

data3 = {'product_name': ['laptop', 'printer', 'tablet', 'desk', 'chair'],'item_name': ['microsoft', 'logitech', 'samsung', 'lg', 'asus'],
        'price': [1500, 100, 200, 350, 400]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)

#creating a list
test=[df1,df2,df3]

#creating a loop for the list
for df in test:
    idx = df.index.get_loc(df[df['item_name'] == 'hp'].index[0])
    vib = df.iloc[idx - 3: idx + 3]
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Hey mozway! So the expected output would be ignoring the message and continue doing the job as intended. So something like ignore if the dataframe is empty. For example, ```df[df['item_name'] == 'lg'``` would run without the error message since there is no empty dataframe.

Comment: @yeppi wrong code except empty dataframe errors. run loop with [df1] instead of test.

Comment: yeah, I was overthinking a bit. Just need to ignore the error message.

Comment: Hey panda, can you elaborate on what you meant?

Comment: run your loop with `for df in [df1]:` instead `for i in test:`. and print `vib`. Is it your desired output?  i thought not.

Comment: Hey panda, thanks for the message! I think the error is coming from the empty dataframe, not the loop itself. Basically, when ```df[df['item_name'] == 'hp'```the third dataframe is empty, creating the error message.

Comment: If `hp` is in 100th row, don't you want to slice from 97 row to 103 row? your code is not possible code. So I don't think fixing error is important problem

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am trying to do. I am trying to slice to capture rows above 3 and rows below 3. Could you provide a sample code so I understand what you are referring to?

Comment: if you run your code by df1, you can know what i say. run your code-->idx = df1.index.get_loc(df1[df1['item_name'] == 'hp'].index[0]);
print(df1.iloc[idx - 3: idx + 3])

Comment: I follow you now! That was actually based on the sample code/data I've created. In the data I am working with, I have more than 5000 rows of 12 data frames. And it does give me what I need at the moment. Thanks so much for the follow-up, Panda.

Comment: I can append each dataframe and create another list

Comment: Your code won't work according to your wish if idx is less than 3 or idx+3 is greater than len(df). if fix that problem, it would naturally solve probem of error also. I was just talking about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore the error and move on,
if that fits your use case.

```
for df in test:
    try:
        idx = df.index.get_loc(df[df['item_name'] == 'hp'].index[0])
        vib = df.iloc[idx - 3: idx + 3]
    except IndexError:
        pass
```